# can't reach to my grafana dashboard on k8s cluster using ingress from browser

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana

I've installed `Prometheus` and `Grafana` on my `Kubernetes` cluster using `helm`:

```
 $helm install prometheus prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack
```

All the `pods`, `deployments` and `services` are up and running. When I use port-forwarding like this:

```
kubectl port-forward deployment/prometheus-grafana 3000
```

I can reach my `grafana dashboard` using browser but when I want to use `ingress` instead of `port-forward` the response is:

[image]

and I can't reach to Grafana dashboard.

---

My `ingress` yaml file:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: grafana-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: kong
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /grafana/login
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: prometheus-grafana
            port:
              number: 80
```

and the `prometheus-grafana` service yaml file is :

```
# Please edit the object below. Lines beginning with a '#' will be ignored,
# and an empty file will abort the edit. If an error occurs while saving this file will be
# reopened with the relevant failures.
#
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: prometheus
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: default
  creationTimestamp: "2021-09-15T11:07:30Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: grafana
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 8.1.2
    helm.sh/chart: grafana-6.16.4
  name: prometheus-grafana
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "801373"
  uid: e1f57de9-94d0-460a-a427-4a97fd770e12
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.100.90.147
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.100.90.147
  ports:
  - name: service
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3000
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/name: grafana
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

Comment: The path /grafana/login in the Ingress looks sorta weird to me. Shouldn't you expose the whole /grafana path? Maybe the login page is trying to redirect you to another page but can't, as there's no route to it?

Comment: hi @AndD !
what do you mean by whole path? someting like www.example.com/grafana/login ?

Comment: What I mean is, the Ingress defines only one path, `/grafana/login` with type `Prefix`. Surely Grafana will have other paths other than `/grafana/login` so first thing I'd try is to just use a single path,  `/grafana`. When you use port forward, at which path can you open the grafana dashboard? Because Grafana will probably expects requests to arrive at that same path / paths.

Comment: when i use port-forward i can see the grafana dashboard at `localhost:3000`

Comment: @hesmoh, did you test suggestions from AndD about paths?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak Honestly, I do not understand correctly.
When I enter the address (`ingress_external_ip/grafana/login`)in the browser, I am redirected to `ingress_external_ip/login` and get 404. The same thing happens if I change the path from `grafana/login` to `/grafana`

Comment: Ok, then this explains things. Grafana is a web app and it is expecting to be served directly under the root path of the server. You need to expose it under `/` as a path, use rewrite target rules or serve it under a subdomain of your host. Try if, with path `/`, everything works as expected or not as a first thing.

Comment: thanks @AndD !
I changed my ingress file : added `host: grafana.example.com` and changed `path` to `/` .
Everything works smoothly

Answer (score 0):

I have posted community wiki answer for better visibility. The problem is solved and it was related to ingress yaml file.

Solution:

> I changed my ingress file : added  `host: grafana.example.com`  and changed  `path`  to  `/`  . Everything works smoothly.

The suggestion of the solution:

> What I mean is, the Ingress defines only one path,  `/grafana/login`  with type  `Prefix`. Surely Grafana will have other paths other than  `/grafana/login`  so first thing I'd try is to just use a single path,  `/grafana`. When you use port forward, at which path can you open the grafana dashboard? Because Grafana will probably expects requests to arrive at that same path / paths.

Explanation:

> Grafana is a web app and it is expecting to be served directly under the root path of the server. You need to expose it under `/` as a path, use rewrite target rules or serve it under a subdomain of your host. Try if, with path `/`, everything works as expected or not as a first thing